# Keyboard Issues

Tags: shortcut

I just encountered something that is now blocking me completely from 3D modeling altogether.  I am hoping that posting here might garner some help.  I have tried various solutions from the net (se below) and none helped, so I am at a block:

I tried to boot Blender 3.5 today.  I forget the exact version number, but it was 3.5.x  I could not use any keyboard shortcuts.  In search fields only certain characters of my keyboard were recognizable.  Those were:

KEYBOARD:

```
` / [ ] \ ; ' { } | : " < > ?
Backspace
Delete
Enter
```

With SHIFT key:

```
~ ^ _
```

NUMPAD:

```
/ * - + .
Enter
```

Suffice it to say I was baffled.  I tried the obvious solutions, shutting down Blender and restarting.  This did not help.  So I rebooted my entire laptop.  That did not help, either.  So I tried deleting ALL files from **\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender**.  This did not help, either.

Okay.  Odd.  So I decided it was time for an update anyway.  I go to the Blender site and download/install 3.6.0.  I was annoyed I'd have to reinstall my add-ons again and have to reconfigure everything to my liking, but … ouch.  I didn't get a chance.  My fresh new install of 3.6.0 has the exact same issue.

I have searched the web and the ONLY folks who have EVER had this issue or anything even close were having these issues because of some addon called "Blender Kit".  I do not have this, and to verify I managed to get into add-ons and select "only enabled" to see what I have enabled, and Blender Kit (Whatever that even is) is not one of them, so this is NOT my issue here.

Also, to verify, at the fresh install of 3.6.0 I did not change anything from default, so my keyboard layout should be fine.

Does anyone have any clue what I might do as further steps to resolve this?

Thank you so much in advance for any help, and I hope you all have a safe and wonderful day.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  I solved it.  I recently installed a new anti-keylogger for security purposes and forgot I had that running.  You absolutely cannot ever use an anti-keylogger with any Blender version, so I have to disable it while modeling.